# Layer vault divergence

Tags: version-control

I just stumbled on this coooool project from the maker of layer vault.
http://cosmos.layervault.com/divergence.html

It allows to turn a project branches into subdomains. I think that's amazing to test design and feature variations.

BUT

I'm a bit puzzled by the configuration file:

```
  # config/config.rb

  require File.expand_path('../callbacks', __FILE__)
  Divergence::Application.configure do |config|
  # Change this to the git repository path
  config.git_path = "/var/www/web_app/repository"

  # this to your application's path
  config.app_path = "/var/www/web_app/current"

  # and this to a location for the cache
  config.cache_path = "/var/www/web_app/cache"

  config.forward_host = 'localhost'
  config.forward_port = 81
end
```

I've tried to set up the git_path, app_path and i have no idea where i should point the cache_path (I believe it's optimised for rails at the moment, but i'm not sure). 
Anyway, its not going anywhere and i keep getting a prompt telling to set up the git_path.
I was wondering if anybody had any luck with it?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the [test directory](https://github.com/layervault/divergence/tree/master/test) included in the [divergence repo](https://github.com/layervault/divergence), and see where those variables are pointing to.

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test
```

It will use this [test git repo](https://github.com/layervault/divergence-test).

- `git_path` points to the root directory of a checked out git repo: see [this commit](https://github.com/layervault/divergence/commit/4b287adfce1d4f3f4acf348a2292aaf3c1254bc2).
- `git_app` refers to any directory in which you want your current branch to be checked out (and your app being deployed)
- `git_cache` points to any directory (even if it doesn't exist yet, it will be created) you want to use for cache.